# Possible semantics for categorical  co-constness

Tags: ct.category-theory, heuristics

In category theory a morphism is constant IIF it is absorbing (for left composition).
 That is a morphism $k$ from $k:A\rightarrow B$ is constant 
if an only if for any two parrallel (same domain and same codomain) morphisms $f$ and $g$ of codomain $A$ we have $k(f) = k(g)$.

Now $c$ is co-constant IIF it is constant in the opposite category (equationally $f(c) = g(c)$ for any $f$ ...) .
Semantically (in Set at least) constness is rather clear , that is a non mathematician understands the idea of "unchanging", the question(s) is:

**Q1**: For constness are there other semantic appearing in something else than $Set$.

**Q2** :What does it mean (semantically) to be coconstant in $Set$ and elsewhere ?

*Note*: I guess there are several (categorically prototypical) answers in both questions.

*Remark* : I thought of something like an unchanging measure of noise (constant) versus an intrinsically flat noise (coconstant). But this is a rather foggy intuition, moreover I cannot categorify it properly.

Comment: *Remark* : The definition of constant is the one from nLab not that of Lawvere (factoring through the terminal object).

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*: This is not quite right -- the two definitions of constantness are not equivalent even in the category of sets, which means that the representability argument doesn't quite work.  See the [nlab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+morphism) for details, but note that they are equivalent if the hom sets $C(X,A)$ are inhabited for every X, or equivalently if A admits a global section.

This doesn't answer all of your questions, but...

A morphism is constant in your sense iff it is representably constant in (what you say is) Lawvere's sense, that is if $k_* \colon C(X,A) \to C(X,B)$ factors through the terminal object in Set.  So if C itself has a terminal object then the two are equivalent.

A morphism c is co-constant iff $c^* \colon C(B,Y) \to C(A,Y)$ is constant, and it's easy to see that if C has an initial object then it's equivalent to ask that c factor through it.  But in Set the initial object $\emptyset$ is strict, meaning that any morphism into $\emptyset$ is an isomorphism.  So there are no non-trivial co-constant morphisms in Set, or indeed in any category with a strict initial object (such as (by a result of Joyal) any cartesian closed category with initial object, like a topos).

I can't tell off the top of my head whether your definition would be useful elsewhere, but the above does put some restrictions on what sorts of categories non-trivial co-constant morphisms might turn up in.

Comment: @Finn : The Lawvere definition implies the nlab definition, but i cannot see the reverse implication in a category with a terminal object.   

Comment: If each function $f \mapsto kf$ factors through the terminal set, then the natural transformation $k_* \colon C(-,A) \to C(-,B)$ factors through the constant functor at the terminal set.  If C has a terminal object T then it represents that functor, so by the full faithfulness of the Yoneda embedding $k = ! \circ b$ for some $b \colon T \to B$, where $! \colon A \to T$.

Comment: @Finn : Sorry I still do not see how this show that nlab definition ( on morphisms not functors) implies Lawvere ( assuming only a terminal object) ? 

Comment: Do you understand why it is that if a morphism k is nLab-constant in C then the natural transformation $C(-,k)$ is Lawvere-constant in $[C^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathrm{Set}]$?

Comment: @Finn :I found a counter example (C.E.): Let $C$ has two objects $A$ and $B$, an arrow $f$ from $A$ to $B$ and the two identities arrows then $f$ is nLab constant (vacuously) but NOT Lawvere. 
Another C.E. is $A={x,y}$ ,B={u,v} ,C={u',v'} , T={t}$ as morphisms add all applications to $T$ (the terminal element). 
Add morphisms $f,g,h$ with $f(u)=u',f(v)=v'$ , $g(x)=u ,g(y)=v$ , $h(x)=v ,h(y)=u$.  Now clearly $f(g)=f(h)$ : $f$ is nLab-constant but not Lawvere. 
More generally if $g$ and $h$ have the same $B$ fibers it gives a C.E..
The idea is nLab means "absorbing" , Lawvere is "one valued". 

Comment: @Finn :I found a counter example (C.E.): Let C has two objects A and B, an arrow f from A to B and the two identities arrows then f is nLab constant (vacuously) but NOT Lawvere. 
Another C.E. is A=x,y ,B={u,v} ,C={u',v'} , T={t} as morphisms add all applications to T (the terminal element). Add morphisms f,g,h with f(u)=u',f(v)=v',g(x)=u ,g(y)=v,h(x)=v ,h(y)=u. Now clearly f(g)=f(h):f is nLab-constant but not Lawvere.
More generally if g and h have the same B-fibers it gives a C.E.
The idea is nLab means "absorbing" , Lawvere is "one valued".

Comment: In your first example, B is the terminal object of C, and f factors through it.  In your second example, fgx=u' but fhx=v', so fg and fh are not equal.  The equivalence of the two definitions of constantness is a straightforward application of the usual facts about representable functors and Yoneda's lemma.  I suggest you study those more closely, and try to answer for yourself the question I asked above (Mar. 13).